# Display current GPS or GEO location on website map

Tags: html, mobile, gps, location, maps

Is there a way to display your current location on a website by using your phone or GPS receiver and Google maps (or something similar)?

Basically, I have a client that has a tourist business on a river and they wish to display their current 'live' location (Updating every 10 - 30 seconds).

Is this possible? And if so, what is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution consists of two parts (I assume your client is on a boat on the river and the map should show the boat's location; your question isn't too clear):

1. The business needs a web page with a (e.g.) Google Map on it. The page displays a pin with the current boat location
2. The boat needs a GPS receiver and a cellular data module that reports the current position from the GPS to some piece of software on the web server (via cell data). The server uses this position report to update the map.

There are off-the shelf hardware parts for the second point.

Comment: Hi Beat Bolli, yes - the client is on a boat on the River and it's the boats location that I want to display (sorry I wasn't very clear in the question). 

They currently have a web page utilising a Google Map. (so step 1 is covered).

They do not currently have a GPS receiver so I'll have to look into that (unless an iPhone can be used for this sort of thing?). RE: There are off-the shelf hardware ... Can you suggest any?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Dan! It's a bit difficult to suggest hardware. Search for "GSM GPRS module" or "GPS CDMA module" depending on your client's cell provider. Also ruggedness (water, vibration, etc) is an issue on a boat!

Answer (score 3):

Instamapper was the answer you needed, but that service goes away on 12/13/12. They have a web page and cellphones upload your GPS location. After that I'm not sure how this will be done.

Answer (score 0):

There are many API's for Goole Maps and Earth.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html

This will probably be the language you will use.

http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/

Comment: Thanks for your input colechristensen but do you have a more detailed answer - for example: To display your location via your mobile/gps receiver you need to do x,y,z. To display the location on the website, you will need to a,b,c ...etc. ?

Comment: There are several different routes you could take, and someone may already have a canned solution for your problem.  "Best" depends on the skills and resources you have available along with desires features.


In any case, all of the information you need is in those links.  It will take a little research on your part.  If you have more specific questions, ask away, but don't ask others to do your homework for you.

Comment: ha, I'm not asking anyone to do my homework for me. I've searched high and low for details on how to achieve what I am wanting to do however haven't been able to find it - that's why I posted my question up here. Usually when someone answers a question on SO, they don't just say "Here's some links - go sort it out" - they usually give a detailed answer explaining it as best as they can.

Comment: Those are the tools, they include good examples and documentation. RTFM

Comment: RTFM hey. Man, your a real charmer - could explain why you only have 26 rep points ... Don't bother writing back - thanks for the links.

Answer (score 0):

I made [Tracman](https://tracman.org/) to let you do this.  You download [an android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=us.keithirwin.tracman) which sends your location to a server by websockets.  Then you get a URL with a map, which you can also embed in your website.  Here's [an example](https://keithirwin.us/location) on my site.

Comment: Thanks @Keith. I have just checked your example however all I can see is a cat in a box - 503 service unavailable haha.

Comment: Yep, I got [some moths in my tubes](https://github.com/Tracman-org/Server/issues/1).  Trying to fix it right now.  Beta version, you know.  Try again tomorrow.